# What is the difference between "<br />\n";and "<br />";

Tags: php

I am new to php,there is a statement confused me.

```
<?php
$dom=new Document();
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://php.net');
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
$nodes = $xml->xpath('//a[@href]');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node['href'], "<br />\n";
}
?>
```

If we change `echo $node['href'], "<br />\n";` into `echo $node['href']."<br />";` ,it has the same effect,same output in my web page,i want to know 
What is the difference between `echo "some string",<br />\n";` and `echo

"some string".<br />";` ?

Comment: If you look at the html output the difference is that with the first example: `<br />\n` you will have a break line in the html output and in the source code. And with the second: `<br />` You will only have a break line in the html output and none in the source code

Comment: what does `in the source code` mean here?

Comment: Press `ctrl + U` in your browser. That means the source code (HTML of the page). `\n` is newline character. It is not rendered by the browser, but viewing the textual output will give you a new line, whereas the `<br />` without `\n` won't do so. Technically it's a character that's not needed when working with HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<br />` is a HTML line-break, whereas `\n` is a newline character in the source code.

In other words, `<br />` will make a new line when you view the page as rendered HTML, whereas `\n` will make a new line when you view the source code.

Alternatively, if you're outputting to a console rather than somewhere that will be rendered by a web browser then `\n` will create a newline in the console output.