# when to choose < br > vs \n to make a new line in vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, newline, break, html-escape-characters

why in `.innerhtml=` the < br > works but not inside `alert()`?

"this is within the scope of vanilla javascript"

Comment: `<br>` has pretty much nothing to do with JavaScript. You use HTML markup of whatever sort when you're creating HTML content. If you're not creating HTML, then you don't.

Comment: I think the answer you seek is exlained here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/29165296/5001964

Comment: alert() doesn't render HTML